# std::map::erase & iterators

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I have some thing like this code:

```
map<int, string> m;

m[1] = "a";
m[2] = "b";
m[3] = "a";
m[4] = "a";
m[5] = "e";
m[6] = "f";
m[7] = "g";
m[8] = "h";
m[9] = "i";

for (it1 = src.begin(); it1 != src.end(); ++it1) {

    for (it2 = it1; it2 != src.end(); ++it2) {
        if (it2 == it1) {
            continue;
        }

        if (it2->second == it1->second) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%u\n", it2->first);
            src.erase(it2);
        }
    }
}
```

I use `map`, because the elements is not always in this order (1, 2 ...)
So here is the question

In some cases of map values, this code print this

```
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
5
```

How it is possible (skipping `5`), if map sort by container in order 1, 2 ... and so on ?

Comment: -1 for not providing a complete program that demonstrates the problem. Please reduce your sample program to a **complete**, **minimal** program that demonstrates the problem. A *complete* program is one that we can copy-paste into a file and compile as-is. A *minimal* program has no code in it unrelated to the problem. See http://sscce.org for reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `erase` loop is off. The typical idiom is this:

```
for(std::map<K,V>::const_iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end() /* not hoisted! */; /* no increment */ )
{
  // do something
  if (suitable_condition)
  {
    v.erase(it++);
  }
  else
  {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Your code erroneously performs an increment on an invalid iterator (namely `it2` after the `erase`), which is undefined behaviour.

<sub>(For certain other container types, `erase` returns an iterator to the next valid element, so in those cases you would say `it = v.erase(it)`; but the details of the best erasing pattern depend on the concrete container type.)</sub>